# How to sync folders between two Windows Servers in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, synchronization, amazon-vpc

I have two servers running Windows Server 2012 in Amazon Cloud. One is hosted in EC2 (**A**) and another - in VPC (**B**).

I have a folder in the same location on both servers. And I need to sync files from **B** to **A**.

Files are not big (<100 kb) and it's acceptable to have a few minutes delay (real time sync is not necessary).

I know, that there's a built-in feature called [DFS](https://serverfault.com/questions/435197/how-to-synchronize-folders-between-two-windows-server-2012), but it doesn't work in [Amazon Cloud](https://serverfault.com/questions/530423/alternative-to-dfs-r-on-amazon-ec2-windows-servers) and I would like to avoid using S3.

**Is there any simple solution to sync those files from one server to another?**

Answer (score 1):

You can try [minio server](https://github.com/minio/minio), it will fit your use case.

You can download [64-bit](https://dl.minio.io/server/minio/release/windows-amd64/minio.exe) or [32-bit](https://dl.minio.io/server/minio/release/windows-386/minio.exe)

Once you have minio server installed on one of the machine, using [minio client aka mc](https://github.com/minio/mc)

mc implements the following commands

```
  ls        List files and folders.
  mb        Make a bucket or folder.
  cat       Display contents of a file.
  pipe      Write contents of stdin to one or more targets. When no target is specified, it writes to stdout.
  share     Generate URL for sharing.
  cp        Copy one or more objects to a target.
  mirror    Mirror folders recursively from a single source to many destinations.
  diff      Compute differences between two folders.
  rm        Remove file or bucket [WARNING: Use with care].
  access    Manage bucket access permissions.
  session   Manage saved sessions of cp and mirror operations.
  config    Manage configuration file.
  update    Check for a new software update.
  version   Print version.
```

You can use 'mc mirror' command & mirror a particular directory.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would probably be to set up a Windows scheduled task to run a `Robocopy /MIR` job every few minutes or so.

Comment: `robocopy \\source\folder \\destination\folder /MIR /dcopy:T` to keep timestamps in sync